# Angular2 update all clients UI after backend change by 1 client

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, angular2-services

I have an Angular2 application that communicates with a c# WebApi. Upon loading I make a GET call to retrieve a list of objects, subscribe them to an array and display the list using ng2-smart-table. My application works for a single user without any problems, but I don't get the correct behaviour when I add more site users.

Based on whichever type of user is logged in I display 2 different views, both views use the same component and thus have access to the same lists. The role type of the user determines which parameters he/she can change.

Imagine the following scenario: 
I have 2 users; *User A* and *User B*. Both are logged in in a different browser tab/window, have a different role type and see the 2 different views.

**Step 1: User A actions**
On loading the webpage the browser for *User A* calls the Get method to fill the lists which are displayed on their screen. *User A* then clicks on the "Mark" button for a certain object in the list, this sets a boolean property to True in the backend for that object. The updated object is then send back to the frontend and updated in the list.

So far so good. *User A* himself sees the UI updated as the object is now "Marked".

**Step 2: User B actions**
*User B* had already loaded the page and thus has already called the Get method to fill the lists on his end. But since *User A* has since updated an item, *User B* must also see that that specific item is now set to "Marked". This however doesn't happen, the list in *User B*'s browser is different from the one in *User A*'s browser.

**Question**
How do I implement this scenario, so that when any updates to the objects by 1 user are also preceived by the other users?

***Other Info:*** All api calls that edit an object return the edited object, as displayed in the example below.

**Edit:** I was able to implement the function by following this post: http://beyondscheme.com/2016/angular2-discussion-portal . However I want to avoid calling the GET All API call constantly as it would create massive data flows that are seemingly waisted as all I need is 1 item.

**order-information.component**

*GET*

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.orderInformationAddEditList = new LocalDataSource();
    this.orderInformationListDataSource = new LocalDataSource();
    if (this.AuthService.isLoggedIn()) {
      this.OrderInformationService.getAll().subscribe(orderInfo => {
        this.orderInformationList = orderInfo;
        this.orderInformationListDataSource.load(this.orderInformationList);
        //this.NotificationsService.success("Success", "Loaded all items.", { timeOut: 2000, clickToClose: true, showProgressBar: true });
        console.log("Loaded all items");

        if (!this.AuthService.hasRole("desk")) {
          this.userIsDesk = false;
        }
      },
        e => {
          console.log("Error: " + e);
          if (e.status == 0) {
            this.NotificationsService.error("Error", "Unable to connect to API", { timeOut: 0, clickToClose: true });
          }
          if (e.status == 500) {
            console.log(e.json().data);
            this.NotificationsService.error(e.json().data.Name, e.json().data.Message, { timeOut: 0, clickToClose: true });
          }
        })
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['']);      
    }
  }
```

*Mark*

```
markOrderInformation(id: number, event: any) {
this.apiAttempts++;

this.OrderInformationService.markOrderInformation(id).subscribe(orderInfo => {
  console.log("Marked: " + orderInfo.id);
  this.NotificationsService.success("Success", "Marked: " + orderInfo.id, { timeOut: 2000, clickToClose: true, showProgressBar: true });
  this.updateOrderList(orderInfo, false);
  event.confirm.resolve(orderInfo);
  this.apiAttempts = 0;

},
  e => {
    var data = e.json();
    if (e.status == 0) {
      this.NotificationsService.error("Error", "Unable to connect to API. Please try again later..", { timeOut: 0, clickToClose: true });
    }
    if (e.status == 401) {
      this.NotificationsService.error(data.Name, data.message, { timeOut: 0, clickToClose: true });
    }
    if (e.status == 500) {
      if (this.apiAttempts < 4) {
        this.NotificationsService.error("Error", "Verify your input and try again. Attempts: " + this.apiAttempts, { timeOut: 0, clickToClose: true });
      } else {
        this.NotificationsService.error(data.Name, data.Message, { timeOut: 0, clickToClose: true });
        this.apiAttempts = 0;
      }
    }
  })
}
```

**order-information.service**

*GET*

```
  getAll(): Observable<OrderInformation[]> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}`, new RequestOptions({ headers: this.getAuthorizationHeaders() }))
    .map(mapOrderInformationList);
  }
```

*Mark*

```
  markOrderInformation(id: number) {
    return this.http.put(`${this.baseUrl}/` + id + `/mark`, { 
    },
    { headers: this.getAuthorizationHeaders() })
    .map(mapOrderInformation);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the tutorial I found here: http://beyondscheme.com/2016/angular2-discussion-portal , I was able to send a GET request every 5 seconds. This was however extremely expensive as I'm sending alot of data accross the web.

I fixed this by returning a smaller list that holds objects that were only edited recently. I did this by adding a new DateTime column to my Sql entity called: lastUpdated. Now whenever I update an object I change the lastUpdated attribute to DateTime.Now().

Finally I created a new GET request method in the Api called GetUpdatedList, that returns all items that were updated within a specific time frame, I took 3 minutes cause I wasn't sure about how big latency can be but I think 1 minute is more than enough. The list received from the Api is then parsed and edited into the existing array in Angular2.

```
public List<Object> GetUpdatedList() {
 try {
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime before = now.AddMinutes(-3);
    return context.Xdock_controle.Where(order => order.lastUpdated != null && order.lastUpdated <= now && order.lastUpdated >= before).ToList();
 } catch (Exception ex) {
    Logger.log(ex.Message);
    throw ex;
 }
}
```